# Sort letters in a string variable in alphabetical order

Tags: stata

I need to sort a string variable letters in alphabetical order in Stata. Can someone suggest a command or a method to do it?

For example: I have a string variable with 1000 observations. So the method would sort the characters (letters) like this:

```
School--chloos 
sort--orst
akramabad-dabamarka
```

Comment: Try searching for "stata sort list alphabetical order" on google, if you have any further issues with this subject.

Comment: dabamarka is wrong!

Comment: `dabamarka` is `akramabad` reversed, not alphabetised.

Comment: Thank you! I searched it before. I could only get commands and techinque to sort a list of variables and a string scalar (one only). However, I need to convert all the string scalar (1000 scalars) to alphabital order each in a newly generated column.

Comment: Each constant in a separate variable (not column)? If you mean that. my advice is that it's a bad idea. In any case, an answer was posted before your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a dataset that size, the easiest way is possibly just to `expand` data briefly to a version with each character in a separate observation. Your question leaves open your rules on lower and upper case, but I'll take your example `"School"` to `"chloos"` literally as implying working with lower case.

```
clear 
input str9 sandbox 
"School" 
"sort" 
"akramabad" 
end 

gen length = length(sandbox) 
gen id = _n 
expand length 
bysort id : gen char = substr(lower(sandbox), _n, 1)
sort id char 
bysort id (char) : gen newbox = char[1] 
by id: replace newbox = newbox[_n-1] + char if _n > 1 
by id: replace newbox = newbox[_N] 
by id: keep if _n == 1 
drop length char 

list 

     +----------------------------+
     |   sandbox   id      newbox |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |    School    1      chloos |
  2. |      sort    2        orst |
  3. | akramabad    3   aaaabdkmr |
     +----------------------------+
```

Creating separate variables for each letter and sorting them within observations would also seem possible.

Comment: Thank you @Nick! This worked really well. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Good. Accepting the answer would give you extra reputation (and me too).